# jQuery if hasClass hide element on blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a form that displays error message in a HTML label when users don't enter valid data into form fields. The label displays beneath the form field onBlur and stays there until data is entered into the form field. I would like the label to only show when users click back into the form field instead of showing persistently. Below is the script where I'm attempting to hide the error label as a user tabs out of the form field. I figured I'd worry about making it appear again once I can effectively hide it.

Here is the HTML:

```
  <div class="field">
     <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" class="error has-error">
     <label for="firstname" class="error">First Name is required.</label>
  </div>
```

And the script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if($('.fieldset #firstname').hasClass('error')) {
    $(this).blur($('.field label')).hide();
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Don't bind handlers within `if` statements. Put your `if` statement inside the handler.

Comment: Based on your code, `$(this)` would refer to window?

Comment: Are you binding a handler to each `input` element individually? Or do you only have the one element? And you want to hide the guidance for an `input` if it's been filled in wrong? That doesn't make a lot of sense (I could imagine hiding the `label` if the `input` is *correctly* filled out, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass a function into the .blur() function as a callback, something like this:

```
$(".fieldset #firstname").blur(function(evt) {
    if($(this).hasClass('error')) {
        $(".field label", $(this).parent()).hide();
    }
});
```

Note that I am doing a .field label selector within the context of the parent() of the $(this). $(this) will refer to #firstname, so if you get the parent, you can easily select within that node tree and not accidentally get some other .field label in your page.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the if condition inside the on blur handler.

```
$('.fieldset #firstname').blur(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('error')){
        $('.field label')).hide();
    }
})
```